# What do the negative and positive signs next to the limit mean?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

I’m sorry for this awkward question, but I don’t know how else I should explain it, I tried to do some research online, but couldn’t find anything. For example, the notation looks like:
$$\lim_{x \to 2^-}f(x)$$
$$\lim_{x \to 2^+}f(x)$$

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-sided_limit).

Answer (score 6):

It's just a way to know what limit you are going to find. When it has a minus sign at the top it means that you must find the limit when the desired $x$ comes from the left, meaning that you must find which number the limit goes as $x$ becomes more closer to $x_0$ from the left. Something similar applies to the positive sign meaning that you find the limit as you come closer to the number of the limit from the right.